# What exactly is term 'segment' in Nutch terminology?

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I just got started on working with Nutch 1.6. I performed my initial crawling which went successful until the point where I came across the following issue:

> LinkDb: adding segment:
>   file:/var/apache-nutch/crawl/segments/2013031234747 LinkDb: adding
>   segment: file:/var/apache-nutch/crawl/segments/2013031250939 Exception
>   in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input
>   path does not exist:
>   file:/var/apache-nutch/crawl/segments/20130308114306/parse_data Input
>   path does not exist:
>   file:/var/apache-nutch/crawl/segments/20130312135244/parse_data
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:197)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:40)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:989)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:981)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:824)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1261)
>       at org.apache.nutch.crawl.LinkDb.invert(LinkDb.java:180)
>       at org.apache.nutch.crawl.LinkDb.invert(LinkDb.java:151)
>       at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:143)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
>       at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)

I would like to understand what is exactly being "segmented" in nutch? In the start of the above error, it says "LinkdB: adding segment.." what is it trying to do? what are we segmenting?

Answer (score 2):

Segment is a partition [hadoop input partition] created, by the map reduce jobs run by nutch, to start crawling from the input set of seed URL's given to crawler to crawl.

Comment: Thanks abhinav.Could you also please explain how nutch decides how many segments to create?